# Not possible to find any compatible framework version even if it does exist

Tags: .net, .net-core

I'm using WSL2 and have a problem with the `dotnet tool` command.

1. I've got an old installation in the */usr/..*
2. I only use the installation in my home directory `~/.dotnet/`
3. I can confirm that I run the `~/.dotnet/dotnet` tool.

```sh
x@y ~> dotnet --version
5.0.200
x@y ~> /usr/bin/dotnet --version
3.1.404
x@y ~> ~/.dotnet/dotnet --version
5.0.200
```

4. I've installed the [gitversion](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GitVersion.Tool/) tool in the global location *~/.dotnet/toools*.

```sh
dotnet tool install GitVersion.Tool -g
```

5. It is properly installed in the correct location *~/.dotnet/tools*.
6. When I run `dotnet-gitversion` (or via `dotnet gitversion`, `~/.dotnet/dotnet gitversion`) I get the following error

```sh
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '5.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.10 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
```

--> Hence, it seems to try to use the "old" installation - why?

**Cheers, Mario :)**

`dotnet --info` outputs the following:

```sh
x@y ~> dotnet --info

.NET SDK (reflecting any global.json):
 Version:   5.0.200
 Commit:    70b3e65d53

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /home/martoffi/.dotnet/sdk/5.0.200/

Host (useful for support):
  Version: 5.0.3
  Commit:  c636bbdc8a

.NET SDKs installed:
  2.1.808 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.302 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.401 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/sdk]
  3.1.402 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/sdk]
  5.0.200 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.20 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.20 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.6 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.7 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.8 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 5.0.3 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.0 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.20 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.2.8 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.6 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.7 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.8 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 5.0.3 [/home/martoffi/.dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```